# synaptic quick search in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Apparently it has changed since Ubuntu 14.04. Let's say, I want to install a library called 'foo'. In the past typing 'foo' into search field would bring up everything, but now I have to type 'libfoo' if I want to make sure that the package 'libfoo-dev' will show up is the search results. Is it possible to to revert it to old behavior?

P.S. Try it with 'leveldb'. Strangely 'libleveldb-java' shows up, but not 'libleveldb-dev'

Comment: The quick search is pretty poor in 16.04+ and by default isn't even enabled anymore, i.e. apt-xapian-index package is no longer on the images. Just use Search instead which is much better/accurate

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of specifics. When I looked up leveldb, the "-dev" package did not come up, but when I searched *lib* leveldb, the package "libleveldb-dev" came up.

If you can't find a package in synaptic, attempting to install it in Terminal via `apt-get` [`sudo apt-get install libleveldb-dev`] will try to find the package from your package lists. Though not as easy as using Synaptic's quick search, it is a workaround.